# GitLab runner using more recent release of Node than installed on server

Tags: windows, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I currently have a Windows GitLab runner installed on a Windows server with Node v15.14.0 installed, but when I attempt to run the single job in my pipeline, it appears to run with Node v17.4.0.

What might be the cause for the discrepancy?

[Screenshot of the Node version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRps6.png)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that the GitLab Runner host machine has multiple versions of Node installed.

I would recommend creating another GitLab Runner using the Docker executor, instead of the Shell executor, and [specify an appropriate docker image](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-in-the-gitlab-ciyml-file) (e.g. - `node:15.14.0`) to use for the job.